# Form field not tied to typescript variable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm a newbie with Typescript and I'm going mad with this piece of code.
I'm writing a very simple login form (below a sample, but consider it's just part of the whole form), but `username` field **inside form** is not tied to the `login.Username` data, while `username` field **outside form** works properly.

So what happens is that when I load the page I get the first field filled with data (and data changes inside variable when I type something), while the field inside form remains empty.

I'm sure it's something stupid, but I can't make it work.

```html
{{diagnostic}}

<input class="form-control" type="text"
    required placeholder="Username"
    minlength="7" maxlength="8"
    [(ngModel)]="login.Username"/>

<form #loginForm="ngForm" (submit)="doLogin()">
    <input class="form-control" type="text"
        required placeholder="Username"
        minlength="7" maxlength="8"
        [(ngModel)]="login.Username"/>
</form>
```

I also attach the component whose html is not working

```js
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Router, NavigationExtras} from '@angular/router';

import {AuthService} from '../services/auth.service';
import {LoginInfo} from "../classes/LoginInfo";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-login',
    templateUrl: './login.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./login.component.css'],
    providers: [],
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(public authService: AuthService, public router: Router) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.login = new LoginInfo('john', 'pwd');
        this.message = '';
    }

    public login: LoginInfo;
    public message: string;


    doLogin() {
        this.message = this.login.isValidInfo() ? 'OK' : "ERRORE";
        alert('test');
        //this.router.navigateByUrl('/scheduler');
    }

    get diagnostic() { return JSON.stringify(this.login); }
}
```

**LoginInfo** class

```js
export class LoginInfo {

    public Username: string;
    public Password: string;
    public Stato: number;
    public Messaggio: string;

    constructor(user: string, pwd: string) {
        this.Username = user;
        this.Password = pwd;
        this.Stato = 0;
        this.Messaggio = '';
    }

    public isValidInfo() {
        return this.Username && this.Username != '' && 
               this.Password && this.Password != '';
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you pulled the `FormsModule` into your `app.module.ts` file?
`import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';` `imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule
  ],` It would be nice if comments on SO could be formatted better...

Comment: @Pytth: yes, already done

Comment: @Marco can you post your LoginInfo class . Also try to ad a name property to the username textbox inside form like `name=user`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing a name property that should be present in the form-control inside a form like `name="user"`. So can you try with the below markup

```
<form #loginForm="ngForm" (submit)="doLogin()">
    <input class="form-control" type="text"
        required placeholder="Username"
        minlength="7" maxlength="8" name="user"
        [(ngModel)]="login.Username"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Never in my life I could have imagined that was the problem; I still don't understand why this leads to problems, but now I know :)

Comment: @Marco that was a change done related to ngModel usage in angular release you can read about it more in SO

Comment: @Nilandri: I'm studiyng and reading angular docs and books, but jumping here and there and trying some code to make it more interesting... so I'm sure it's written somewhere in the docs, but probably I've missed it :D